# What is the use of Wordpress/Joomla?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, joomla

I am developing a travels related website using cakephp. I have to put some tour itinerary/special vacation campaign etc. on it almost everyday. The template/format remain the same, just the content changes. So, I am guessing that I can use some content management system like Wordpress/Joomla here.

Till now I had been working mainly on static pages only, but from now I will work on including search functions, forums, members area, polls, etc. in the website.

Can somebody tell me if switching to these CMS technologies is a good idea?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla would be apt for you. Because Its going to be something like a website. Hence you can choose joomla, also there are lot of joomla templates available, you can customise to your needs.

Wordpress would not be right for you since its a blogging tool. Unless until you need blogging functionality you need not have wordpress.

There is also something like drupal,

You may read here for better clarity [here](http://www.goodwebpractices.com/other/wordpress-vs-joomla-vs-drupal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is really a good idea. Using already built CMS saves time and increases the customization. For Wordpress, there are thousands of plugin which can transform WP into a CMS.

Also, security will be good if a CMS is used. You will get regular updates for stability.

Check this page: [Need a simple CMS. Should I customise an existing CMS or build from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176829/need-a-simple-cms-should-i-customise-an-existing-cms-or-build-from-scratch)